# Вывод Json в табличку HTML

Tags: html, json, golang

Вопрос тот же, что и в заголовке, любые легкие и не легкие способы, которые есть.

Код на go (создает json)

```
package main



    import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
    )



    type MainStruct struct {
        Id int
        Surname string
    }

    type RandomStruct struct {
        Array []MainStruct
    }

    func main() {
        JsonData := &RandomStruct{
            Array: []MainStruct{
                MainStruct{
                    Id: 1,
                    Surname: "Ivanov",
                },
                MainStruct{
                    Id: 2,
                    Surname: "Petrov",
                },
                MainStruct{
                    Id: 3,
                    Surname: "Sergeev",
                },
            },
        }

        JsonEncod, _ := json.MarshalIndent(JsonData,"","")
        _ = ioutil.WriteFile("test.json", JsonEncod,0644)
        fmt.Println(string(JsonEncod))
    }
```

и собственно сам json

```
{
"Array": [
{
"Id": 1,
"Surname": "Ivanov"
},
{
"Id": 2,
"Surname": "Petrov"
},
{
"Id": 3,
"Surname": "Sergeev"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону пакета html/template

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, попробуйте воспользоваться шаблонами https://gowebexamples.com/templates/
Или же делать это с помощью JS